# How to set and get some data from file in real time

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, configuration

I want to develop a system which show some numbers. These numbers are changed with some reasons.

The number of these numbers is just 5, so I think using database system is little bit too much. Therefore, I hope that the value stored in a file (XML or something) can be viewed and modified in real time on the server.

If this method is possible, please give me a small hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to read and write from a file. Especially if the file is a XML file. There are parsers and helper classes that can help you with it.
Still, you would have to take care of closing the `file`, making sure that there is no inconsistent data and multithreading problems.

All these problems are (at a point) eliminated by using a DataBase system. If you think using a DB is too much, then use a smaller DB where the footprint is very small. For example [H2](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).

Create a small table with your data and let the java driver take care of the complicated stuff for you. The other advantage is the speed that this DB delivers.

Do not forget, that there are strong reasons that people do not use files as DBs

Comment: Hi, @Renis1235. Thanks to your advice, I'm considering to use h2. But as I know h2 is stored in memory. Than how can I handle data when restarting the server?

Comment: I configured out with using server mode H2. Thank you Renis

Comment: @Julia5049 glad I could help!